# Enabling a disabled child window form's maximize button from another process

Tags: c#

I currently do not know how could I get all forms window handle that is created by a single process.

For ex:

Internet explorer creates forms but runs in single process. For some reason one of the child form's maximize button is disabled. How could I Enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Named Pipes to achieve that - http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp

or if you want to some how control other Processes use http://white.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'm kinda lazy and dumb Didn't get what that does. I tried SetWindowLong and GetWindowLong. But I can only apply it on mainwindow because I dont know how to get other windows which is called child windows. And some weird reason even it is mainwindow and I know the handle IntPtr thing I tried to SetWindowLong thing on it but the process' main window transformed into such weird window that I could say it was like borderless.